# Install biomaRt package

Tags: r

I am trying to install this package and I get this warning message

```
install.packages("biomaRt", repo="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
install.packages("biomaRt", type="source")
library("biomaRt”)

  package ‘biomaRt’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://r-forge.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2
```

Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("biomaRt")
library("biomaRt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would love to post an updated version besides AI14's answer in 2015. 
From this webpage, you can install biomaRt as follows: [source](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/biomaRt.html)

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("biomaRt")
```